# How Can I populate dynamic markers on Map using SQLite Database Databae?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I stored Latitude and Longitude into my Database And I want to populate these saved locations's marker on map.

I get data into array list but I have no idea how I populate on map ?

```
   ArrayList<Double> get_location(){

    ArrayList<Double> location = new ArrayList<>();
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select latitude,longitude from "+Table_Name_Location,null);
    if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {                                  
            Double latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Latitude));
            Double longitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Longitude));
            location.add(latitude);
            location.add(longitude);
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    return location;
}
```

Map Activity

```
public class Visited_Places extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_visited__places);
    databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);

    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {


}
```

}

Comment: What if you create model class with latitude and longitude, get lat and long from DB and set it in model and add that model in list. Very simple way

Comment: @MD Sir can you suggest me any reference post ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public class Visited_Places extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    DatabaseHelper databaseHelper;

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> alllocation = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_visited__places);
        databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
        alllocation = get_location();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.maps);

        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
//put multiple location map
        if (googleMap != null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < alllocation.size(); i++) {
                HashMap<String, Object> hash = alllocation.get(i);
                Double lat = (Double) hash.get("latitude");
                Double lang = (Double) hash.get("longitude");
                String address = hash.get("address").toString();

                if (i == 0) {
                    googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat, lang), 14));

                }
                googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(lat, lang))
                        .title(address));


            }
        }


    }
    //getting location from database  
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> get_location(){

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>> location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, Object>>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select address,latitude,longitude from "+Table_Name_Location,null);
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
                Double latitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Latitude));
                Double longitude = cursor.getDouble(cursor.getColumnIndex(Longitude));
                //get your address
                String address = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Address));

                HashMap<String, Object> hash = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hash.put("latitude", latitude);
                hash.put("longitude", longitude);
                hash.put("address", address);
                location.add(hash);
            }
        }
        cursor.close();
        return location;
    }
}
```

Comment: In this code where you are getting data from database ?

Comment: I only get data same as question, only change ArrayList type because arraylist not store key,value.If you want then i made custom arraylist without database.

Comment: Thank you so much sir...but I want also see the place name which is also saved in database

Comment: googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(alllocation.get(i)) .title("Title"))

get address from database and change "Title" string. When you click on marker icon then you able to see your address

Comment: Sir but arrylist type is Latlang ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.

Comment: This exception is given

Comment: Pls change your query in this line
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select latitude,longitude from "+Table_Name_Location,null);

Add your database address field in query like this
 Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select address,latitude,longitude from "+Table_Name_Location,null);

Comment: Welcome :) and be happy always and up vote this answer

Comment: Sir I have one query related to map can you give me idea ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58165815/how-can-i-calculate-distance-between-multiple-latitude-and-longitude